# react-native0.44, i am use fetch request "http", but network request failed?

Tags: react-native

i'm from official find fetch only support `https`, but now, i use Mock data, the url is `http`, official said if support `http` must change `info.plist`, add `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, below the image:

[image: infoPlist seetting]

i add `App Transport Security Settings` and children row `Allow Arbitrary Loads`,

the request `http` not support! please ask how to resolve support Mock `http` request in react-native ? Thanks!

i use Mock is Alibaba "Rap" [Mock address](http://www.rapapi.org/), it's only support Mock `http` request!

Comment: Can you post your error message?

Comment: error: network request failed

Comment: Did you recompile your app after changing Info.plist? i.e. rerun `react-native run-ios`

Comment: i restart project from xcode, and now is ok! hahaha!  it is strange! goodnight! thanks friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Info.plist will take effect after recompiling your app.

Probably you need to recompile your app by rerun `react-native run-ios` or rerun from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` must be set to `false`.
Instead you should add an exception to your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Right now you are exposing your device to vunerabilities.

Checkout this [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544)

Comment: i add App Transport Security Setting and Allow Arbitrary Loads restart project ，is ok！your method  should be resolve the error！thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) and [this](http://www.timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/). Your method for setting the content loading is not secure.